# Difference between normal and abnormal termination C++

Tags: c++, return-value

**C++** **:**
What is the difference between return 0 (normal termination) and return 1 (abnormal termination) ? what does abnormal termination have to do with the destructors

Comment: ***what does abnormal termination have to do with the destructors*** Nothing at all.

Comment: @drescherjm, you are correct, but surely [`std::exit(-45)`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/program/exit) may not call destructors of objects with *automatic storage duration*

Comment: ***What is the difference between return 0 (normal termination) and return 1 (abnormal termination) ?*** When a program fails for whatever reason it is supposed to tell the calling process that it failed. Returning 0 means the program ran successfully. Returning any other number indicates a failure.

Comment: @WhiZTiM agreed.

Comment: Formally, `return 1` has no portable meaning. You can `return EXIT_SUCCESS`, `return EXIT_FAILURE`, or `return 0`. That last one is equivalent to `return EXIT_SUCCESS`. The meaning of any other value depends on your compiler and OS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The app can be started by a script rather than by a user manually. So, returning a error indicator may help the script to alter execution flow according to exact error code returned (so the script can retry the call again after a timeout, or terminate the script with error code for outer script if any, or call an alternative code as a fallback plan, etc.)

Answer (score 1):

In every operating system exit with a return value. Most of the cases it is either `0` successful completion and `1` or any larger or smaller value for  unsuccessful completion. Destructor nothing to do with return with `0` or `1`. Destructor is to release memory inside a programed to avoid memory leak or proper memory management. Hence destructor is nothing to do with exit status of a program. To know whether a program executed successfully or not we can check like below:-

In UNIX you can check the value of `$?` whether process successful or not. It will return `0` if successful and `1` or a larger value to indicate that process failed.

To check a exit status of a process in Windows o/s we use `%errorlevel%`